# Ближайшее и наименьшее к n из двух чисел

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по заданию правильно ли оформлен код или что можно добавить или упростить?

> Создать программу, выводящую на экран ближайшее и наименьшее к 10 из двух чисел, записанных в переменные m и n.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 11;
        int m = 7;
        if (n < m) {
            System.out.println("Ближайщее число к 10 = " + m);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Ближайшее число к 10 = " + n);
        }
        if (n > m) {
            System.out.println("Наименьшее число к 10 = " + m);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Наименьшее число к 10 = " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае ближайшее считает правильно, но если m = 5 и n = 3, то посчитает неправильно. Я бы где-то так считал (псевдокод)

```
if (abs(10-m) < abs(10-n)) 'm ближе' else 'n ближе'.
abs находится в java.lang.Math
```

А вот что такое "Наименьшее число к 10" -  я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вынести System.out.print("Ближайщее число к 10 = ") перед блоком if-else, а внутри оставить только System.out.println(m). Ну и согласен с ответом выше.

Что такое "Наименьшее число к 10"?

Comment: Сорри ошибочка вышла это с другого задания Наименьшее число